# Sqoop from SQL Server with no primary keys

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to do a sqoop import for a table that has few billion records and doesn't have any primary key in the table, so I can't do --split-by any existing column.

Is it possible to split by row number, so I can split the data equally across all mappers.

Can you please help with the command.

Comment: If the table doesn't have a primary key how do you intend to split by row number? Tables have no inherent ordering, even in the presence of a sortable primary key, so there's no guarantee that two different selects on the table would return rows in the same order.

Comment: Order of rows isn't important for me, I want to split the data equally across mappers. for ex. let's say i have 400 million records and i have rownum value for all those, if i split it by rownum and split value is 4, then atleast i can have 100 million records equally in all mappers.

Comment: Unless I've completely misunderstood how Sqoop works mappers run independent select queries, usually in parallel. With no consistent row numbering (from a primary key or some other unique-indexed column) there's no guarantee that four mappers would get disjoint sets, there could well be overlapping members.

Comment: Okay, then what would be the best way to import a table that has few billion records and doesn't have any primary key. I tried giving split-by on other columns that are not distinct, but still the job failed.